# How can I deploy my Reactjs project using Netlify server correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, proxy, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my Reactjs site to Netlify, and while it passes all the tests and has a completed build, when I open the site on Netlify and click the button that triggers the Pexel API, I get a 502 error.

I made a Netlify server function and I'm using the API to make a request to it.
Below is the proxy.js file:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const { PEXELS_API_URL } = require("../../src/constants");

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const { keyword, page } = event.queryStringParameters;

    const response = await axios.get(PEXELS_API_URL(keyword, page), {
      headers: {
        Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_PEXELS_API_KEY,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      },
    });
    console.log("Response Headers:", response.headers);
    console.log("API Response:", response.data);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response.data),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Failed to fetch data" }),
    };
  }
};
```

Here is the Apiload.js file making a request to it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import axios from "axios";
import ImageTiles from "./ImageTiles";
import emotionData from "../emotionData.json";

const Apiload = ({ id, query }) => {
  const [pexelData, setPexelData] = useState({ photos: [] });
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [expandedImageId, setExpandedImageId] = useState("");
  const [selectedImageSrc, setSelectedImageSrc] = useState("");

  // const fetchData = async (keyword) => {
  //   try {
  //     const res = await axios.get(PEXELS_API_URL(keyword, page), {
  //       headers: {
  //         Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_PEXELS_API_KEY,
  //       },
  //     });

  const fetchData = async (keyword) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/.netlify/functions/proxy", {
        params: {
          keyword,
          page,
        },
      });
      console.log("API Response:", res.data);
      setPexelData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        photos: [...prev.photos, ...res.data.photos],
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      fetchData(query);
    } else {
      const emotionItem = emotionData.find((item) => item.id === id);

      if (emotionItem) {
        fetchData(emotionItem.id);
      }
    }
  }, [id, page]);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop + 1 >=
      document.documentElement.scrollHeight
    ) {
      setPage((prev) => prev + 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (imageId, imageSrc) => {
    setExpandedImageId(imageId);
    setSelectedImageSrc(imageSrc);
  };

  const handleExitClick = () => {
    setExpandedImageId("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {pexelData === null ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div className="image-tile-container">
          {pexelData.photos &&
            pexelData.photos.map((ele) => (
              <ImageTiles
                key={ele.id}
                imageSrc={ele.src.medium}
                onClick={() => handleClick(ele.id, ele.src.medium)}
                isExpanded={ele.id === expandedImageId}
                isOversized={ele.id === expandedImageId}
                onExitClick={handleExitClick}
                selectedImageSrc={selectedImageSrc}
                setSelectedImageSrc={setSelectedImageSrc}
                query={query}
              />
            ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Apiload;
```

Before deploying for the first time, my site worked fine locally, but the first error I received from deploying my site was a CORS  error. So I added `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"`, and I still received the 404 CORS error on Netlify. After that I decided to create a Netlify server function/proxy and made the API request in my project to it. I  downloaded the netlify-cli package via npm to see if that would fix anything. Also when I deploy in Netlify although everything says  completed, it keeps telling me that there were no header rules processed.

Does this mean the header rules in my proxy.js file are being ignored?
I switched the header rule to the Apiload.js file from the proxy.js to see if it would be read then, and when I deploy it , it still says header rules are not being read.

Also my site only works locally if I make the request to the Pexel api in my apiload.js file.

Here's my last deployment log:

```
2:54:25 PM: build-image version: 1ae4e4d7d5e3544ab1eb7f270391cdbb47c1e1e5 (focal)
2:54:25 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
2:54:25 PM: buildbot version: 1ae4e4d7d5e3544ab1eb7f270391cdbb47c1e1e5
2:54:26 PM: Finished downloading cache in 1.568s
2:54:26 PM: Starting to extract cache
2:54:25 PM: Starting to download cache of 166.6MB
2:54:29 PM: Finished extracting cache in 2.209s
2:54:29 PM: Finished fetching cache in 3.847s
2:54:29 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
2:54:29 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
2:54:30 PM: Custom functions path detected. Proceeding with the specified path: 'netlify/functions'
2:54:31 PM: Starting to install dependencies
2:54:31 PM: Python version set to 3.8
2:54:31 PM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
2:54:31 PM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
2:54:32 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
2:54:32 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
2:54:32 PM: go version go1.19.10 linux/amd64
2:54:32 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
2:54:33 PM: Started restoring cached Node.js version
2:54:34 PM: Finished restoring cached Node.js version
2:54:34 PM: v18.16.1 is already installed.
2:54:35 PM: Now using node v18.16.1 (npm v9.5.1)
2:54:35 PM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
2:54:35 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
2:54:35 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
2:54:35 PM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
2:54:35 PM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
2:54:35 PM: No npm workspaces detected
2:54:35 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
2:54:35 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
2:54:35 PM: Installing npm packages using npm version 9.5.1
2:54:46 PM: up to date, audited 2558 packages in 11s
2:54:46 PM: 390 packages are looking for funding
2:54:46 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
2:54:46 PM: 74 vulnerabilities (63 moderate, 11 high)
2:54:46 PM: To address issues that do not require attention, run:
2:54:46 PM:   npm audit fix
2:54:46 PM: To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
2:54:46 PM:   npm audit fix --force
2:54:46 PM: Run `npm audit` for details.
2:54:47 PM: npm packages installed
2:54:47 PM: Install dependencies script success
2:54:47 PM: Starting build script
2:54:48 PM: Detected 1 framework(s)
2:54:48 PM: create-react-app at version 5.0.1
2:54:48 PM: Section completed: initializing
2:54:49 PM: ​
2:54:49 PM: Netlify Build                                                 
2:54:49 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:54:49 PM: ​
2:54:49 PM: ❯ Version
2:54:49 PM:   @netlify/build 29.15.3
2:54:49 PM: ​
2:54:49 PM: ❯ Flags
2:54:49 PM:   baseRelDir: true
2:54:49 PM:   buildId: 64ab025f8398160008bf8696
2:54:49 PM:   deployId: 64ab025f8398160008bf8698
2:54:50 PM: ​
2:54:50 PM: ❯ Current directory
2:54:50 PM:   /opt/build/repo
2:54:50 PM: ​
2:54:50 PM: ❯ Config file
2:54:50 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
2:54:50 PM: ​
2:54:50 PM: ❯ Context
2:54:50 PM:   production
2:54:50 PM: ​
2:54:50 PM: Build command from Netlify app                                
2:54:50 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:54:50 PM: ​
2:54:50 PM: $ CI= npm run build
2:54:50 PM: > moodboard@0.1.0 build
2:54:50 PM: > react-scripts build
2:54:51 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
2:54:51 PM: (node:3744) [DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_NORMAL_MODULE_LOADER_HOOK] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.hooks.normalModuleLoader was moved to NormalModule.getCompilationHooks(compilation).loader
2:54:51 PM: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2:54:56 PM: (node:3744) [DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_ASSETS] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.assets will be frozen in future, all modifications are deprecated.
2:54:56 PM: BREAKING CHANGE: No more changes should happen to Compilation.assets after sealing the Compilation.
2:54:56 PM:     Do changes to assets earlier, e. g. in Compilation.hooks.processAssets.
2:54:56 PM:     Make sure to select an appropriate stage from Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_*.
2:54:56 PM: Compiled with warnings.
2:54:56 PM: 
2:54:56 PM: Warning
2:54:56 PM: (629:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
2:54:56 PM: Warning
2:54:56 PM: (654:3) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
2:54:56 PM: Warning
2:54:56 PM: (735:5) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
2:54:56 PM: [eslint]
2:54:56 PM: src/components/Apiload.js
2:54:56 PM:   Line 6:10:  'PEXELS_API_URL' is defined but never used                                                                                  no-unused-vars
2:54:56 PM:   Line 53:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'fetchData' and 'query'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2:54:56 PM: src/pages/Personalboard.js
2:54:56 PM:   Line 7:10:  'images' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2:54:56 PM: src/pages/SearchResults.js
2:54:56 PM:   Line 9:22:   'setSearchParams' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2:54:56 PM:   Line 10:10:  'page' is assigned a value but never used             no-unused-vars
2:54:56 PM: Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
2:54:56 PM: To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
2:54:56 PM: File sizes after gzip:
2:54:56 PM:   80.73 kB  build/static/js/main.aac7c9e3.js
2:54:56 PM:   2.91 kB   build/static/css/main.8504852c.css
2:54:56 PM:   1.78 kB   build/static/js/988.d8d2d73d.chunk.js
2:54:56 PM: The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
2:54:56 PM: You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
2:54:56 PM: The build folder is ready to be deployed.
2:54:56 PM: You may serve it with a static server:
2:54:56 PM:   npm install -g serve
2:54:56 PM:   serve -s build
2:54:56 PM: Find out more about deployment here:
2:54:56 PM:   https://cra.link/deployment
2:54:56 PM: ​
2:54:56 PM: (build.command completed in 6.5s)
2:54:56 PM: ​
2:54:56 PM: Functions bundling                                            
2:54:56 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:54:56 PM: ​
2:54:56 PM: Packaging Functions from netlify/functions directory:
2:54:56 PM:  - proxy.js
2:54:56 PM: ​
2:54:56 PM: ​
2:54:56 PM: (Functions bundling completed in 284ms)
2:54:56 PM: ​
2:54:56 PM: Deploy site                                                   
2:54:56 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:54:56 PM: ​
2:54:56 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'build'
2:54:56 PM: Calculating files to upload
2:54:57 PM: 4 new files to upload
2:54:57 PM: 1 new functions to upload
2:55:03 PM: Starting post processing
2:55:04 PM: Skipping HTML post processing
2:55:04 PM: Post processing - header rules
2:55:04 PM: Post processing - redirect rules
2:55:04 PM: Post processing done
2:55:04 PM: Section completed: postprocessing
2:55:05 PM: Site is live ✨
2:55:03 PM: Section completed: deploying
2:55:03 PM: Site deploy was successfully initiated
2:55:03 PM: ​
2:55:03 PM: (Deploy site completed in 7s)
2:55:03 PM: ​
2:55:03 PM: Netlify Build Complete                                        
2:55:03 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:55:03 PM: ​
2:55:03 PM: (Netlify Build completed in 13.8s)
2:55:04 PM: Caching artifacts
2:55:04 PM: Started saving node modules
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving node modules
2:55:04 PM: Started saving build plugins
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving build plugins
2:55:04 PM: Started saving corepack cache
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving corepack cache
2:55:04 PM: Started saving pip cache
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving pip cache
2:55:04 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
2:55:04 PM: Started saving go dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
2:55:04 PM: Build script success
2:55:04 PM: Section completed: building
2:55:05 PM: Uploading Cache of size 166.5MB
2:55:07 PM: Section completed: cleanup
2:55:07 PM: Finished processing build request in 42.193s
```

I need help figuring out why I'm receiving this error, and how to fix it. I'm new to coding and debugging so any help I would greatly appreciate. Please let me know if you would need anymore info on my end.

Below is the error:

> react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 Error fetching data: Wt {message: 'Request failed with status code 502', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed with status code 502"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}data: {errorType: 'Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError', errorMessage: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'", trace: Array(5)}headers: n {age: '1', cache-control: 'no-cache', content-type: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', date: 'Sun, 09 Jul 2023 18:58:14 GMT', server: 'Netlify', …}request: XMLHttpRequestonabort: ƒ ()onerror: ƒ ()onload: nullonloadend: ƒ d()onloadstart: nullonprogress: nullonreadystatechange: nullontimeout: ƒ ()readyState: 4response: "{"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'","trace":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1195:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1201:1"]}"responseText: "{"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'","trace":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1195:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1201:1"]}"responseType: ""responseURL: "https://master--extraordinary-sprite-9b3b15.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/proxy?keyword=happy&page=1"responseXML: nullstatus: 502statusText: ""timeout: 0upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}withCredentials: false[[Prototype]]: XMLHttpRequeststatus: 502statusText: ""[[Prototype]]: Objectstack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 502\n    at [https://master--extraordinary-sprite-9b3b15.netlify.app/static/js/main.aac7c9e3.js:2:228095\n](https://master--extraordinary-sprite-9b3b15.netlify.app/static/js/main.aac7c9e3.js:2:228095%5Cn)    at XMLHttpRequest.d (https://master--extraordinary-sprite-9b3b15.netlify.app/static/js/main.aac7c9e3.js:2:228243)"[[Prototype]]: Error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.